# How do i turn off animation in login screen of Window 7, and location of the current .msstyles file

Tags: windows-7

My Laptop have install a desktop theme, "HyperDesk", which looks quite good, and i have done a few customization on it.

It have 3 account:
Admin
KAV
Myself

so far i have set the system running in best performance, then tick drop shadow, smooth screen font, visual styles and desktop composition.

The problem i got is that my login screen keep features animations, and also the system property keep change to best looking after i log off or restart

It seems that is affecting by the different visual styles (.msstyles) of different account, Where can i locate the current msstyles files ?

I did it manually:

[image]

after logout and login again:

[image]

Startup in registry:

[image]

Startup in StartMenu:

[image]

ease of access settings:

[image]

Theme folder:

[image]

The msstyles files i am using:

[image]

Comment: only workable solution will be accept as solution, while registry change with explanation or group policy settings with workable config is expected.

Comment: tunning        HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VisualEffects is known, more details is needed

Comment: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\UserPreferencesMask   seems to be another tuning area, but also cannot get it work due to the UAC issues.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this might be a solution why not try with turn off unnecessary animations? To do follow these steps:

1. Navigate To `Control Panel`
2. Switch to `Icon view` for Better view
3. Choose `Ease of access Center`
4. Choose `Use the Computer Without A display`
5. Check `Turn-off all unnecessary animations`

The .msstyles would be located by default at `C:\WINDOWS\Resources\Themes\`

Hope it helps.

Comment: It just keep turning on automatically every time i log out or restart. can't found what things switch it on. was beginning from around 1 month ago.

Comment: check the themes folder, doesn't found anything abnormal

Comment: i think that nothing have change the msstyles file.